# Fiber Optics as a video source and a switch?

Tags: arduino, video, touchscreen

1. Is it possible to put a fiber optic bundle together and play video thru the colors of the tips (if they were all flush next to each other
2. Is it possible to touch the end of fiber optics with hand or any object and receive the signal on the other end?

For example, if i had a grid of 50 x 50 fiber optic cables and I was looking at the flat ends side-by-side I would like to be able to display a graphic that can recognize touch.

Comment: That's how an endoscope is built, one of my collegues at Uni for his final year project worked out how to do this with just *ONE* fiber, he had some serious adaptive optics but it worked, so yes you can most certainly play a video over a bundle of fiber optic cables - just make sure they're arranged in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming you could keep the grid organized so that you knew the order/position of each fibre.

Additionally, in order to recognize touch, you'll probably want to look at reflected light on a per-fibre basis, which will require non-trivial optics and electronics. Alternatively, you could embed capacitive sensors in the "end" of the cable, but this ruins the optical isolation and its associated advantages.

You should really consider if it's possible to use a simple LCD w/ touchscreen.

Comment: Does this accomplish the touch aspect as well? What cheap components could I buy to prototype it with Arduino or Raspberry Pi? Unfortunately, simple touch screen would not work, because it would need to handle more pressure and infinite multi-point feedback

Comment: Since you have some rather serious requirements, here's how I would do such a thing: inject light into an adjacent fibre (or several), and look at the returned light in the fibre of interest. As for accomplishing this with an Arduino or Raspberry Pi: for any decent number of fibres, no. You simply don't have the required scan speed or GPIO pins. Maybe for sixteen fibres or something.

Comment: What keywords should I use to look for 1) the touch sensitivity of the tip of the fiber and 2) the fiber grid as video?

Comment: Haven't the foggiest. This isn't exactly a COTS type thing, you're probably going to have to design the entire system from scratch, optics, light sources, photodetectors, and all.

Comment: This looks interesting. How was this achieved? (link is broken) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvGagCSTemk -- Perhaps something similar to this, but should handle touch of any kind of object, not just a hand. I was thinking there might be a way to use a color LED and then simply detect if there is resistance at the end. Would handle the color and touch aspect

Answer (score 1):

A flexible coherent fiber bundle can be made; fiber-channel-plate products exist, as well, and there's a mineral, ulexite, that naturally has this property.
It's possible to see (for instance) reflections from an object
touching the fiber plate ends (just like a finger on an aquarium shows
a fingerprint in a mirror-like surround when viewed from the other side
of the glass).

There's some fascinating gadgets with fiber electron multipliers in a
plate.   They make image intensifiers, like for night-vision systems. 
You can't afford one, but military forces can.

Comment: Does this accomplish the touch aspect as well? What cheap components could I buy to prototype it with Arduino or Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Fiber electron multipliers operate in a vacuum, so you can't directly touch them.   You can put a phosphor dot at the end of each fiber, and create images, though.   I'm not familiar with any interface options to digital output, except indirectly (taking a picture); the mass production of aligned fibers doesn't include hierarchical connection (like for addressing individual pixels).